# Can I change Min SDK version for a hosted app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-sdk-tools, android-version

I have hosted an app with Min SDK version as 8 and due to some reasons I wanted to upgrade to 11. So my question is that will Play store accepts this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will accept. But please beware, that users with OS 8, 9, 10 will loose chances of installing your app (they won't see it at all, even older version of app, that has minSDK 8).